How to change the schema history table name
Our app has flyway which has added around 100 migrations to the prod env over the last years.
It uses a table called "schema_version" to track the flyway history.
When we fire up the desktop app, to test new migrations against the staging database, flyway thinks no migrations have ever been done, and wants to apply all 100, not just the last one we added.
We assume this is because the flyway app defaults to looking for the schema history in a tabled called "flyway_schema_history".
How can we configure this in the desktop app?

I think there was some property to change it like "flyway.table=schema_version"
Docs:
https://documentation.red-gate.com/flyway/flyway-cli-and-api/configuration/parameters/flyway/table

Found the answer, although you cant edit the flyway configuration, you can Add this bit under "View Flyway configuration settings" -> Edit configuration file:
[flyway]
table = "my_schema_history_table"

